# Why do winform controls move on their own when I save the form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am having an issue with button controls moving when I close my form in the editor in VS 2012. I am working in C# exclusively. This is diving me nuts as I have to reposition the controls every time I open the designer.

```
Form Size 995, 625

Button             Location
------             --------
Save button        617, 575
Delete button      701, 575
Clear button       785, 575
Cancel button      869, 575
```

Buttons are anchored Bottom,Right

Form Maximum size is 0,0

There is a TabControl above these buttons. I have had this issue before and I am pretty sure it involved a form with a TabControl as well.

There are a couple layers of inheritance below this form, but both are defined smaller. The buttons in play here are inherited from the form just below this one. On that form they are anchored Top,Left so I would think my controls would be moving up and left if they were being effected by that forms positioning. They consistently move down and right.

Steps that reproduce.

- Position the controls as above. (No further edits)
- Save the form. (no visible change yet)
- Close the form.
- Reopen the form and the controls are located as follows:

```
 Button              Location
 Save button         852, 664   (off visible form)
 Delete button       936, 631   (off visible form)
 Clear button       1020, 630   (off visible form)
 Cancel button      1104, 664   (off visible form)
```

These locations vary. Sometimes they are still on the form, or partially on-form just in a lower position and no longer aligned. They are always lower and to the right as if they were being effected by a changing form size during the closing process.

If I make the form larger in the designer, they just keep moving down and right staying off-form.

I have resorted to positioning them programmatically for now, but would rather understand what is happening so as to prevent it in the future.

Comment: I hate to say it, but most of the small picky issues with designers you just have to give up on. The only real solution is to position the controls themselves programmatically and ignore what the designer shows you.

Comment: Also, have you checked if you have write rights on the partial class physical file and that it is not read-only?

Comment: Pretty sure I have rights, all other changes are saving.

Comment: I have edited your question a bit to try to remove the wall of text and make it a bit clearer.. but its still a little unclear as to what the actual problem is.. Do you mean whenever you save the form in the designer window your controls move? Have you modified the designer.cs files manually?

Comment: Sayse - Thanks for the cleanup. They move when I CLOSE the window and re-open, not save.  Unless it is simply not refreshing after the save. No manual edits to the designer.cs.

Comment: So we're talking about when working in visual studio here with designing the form (not a save function of your form when running your application)? Do you have any code before `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: For the record, my thinking would be the problem is something to do with what gets called in the forms constructor which is what visual studio uses to display the form in the editor window (sort of) and also create your form (`InitializeComponent`).. When inheritance is involved things really get confusing very quickly for VS from my experience

Comment: Hans Passant, you may have a point there. There is no need for my base class to anchor them anywhere as they are normally moved anyway. However the base class has them anchored top,left. The derived class has them bottom,right. You would think they would move up and left if the parent was influencing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens often if you have a base form (or user control) where you set some anchors for the controls and in derived designer your form has a different size.

A possible solution is to forget anchoring and to use docking instead. You can achieve everything by using the `Dock`, `Margin` and `Padding` properties; however, it can be strange for the first time that you might need to use many invisible panels (for example when you want to use two lines of controls below each other). This is a similar approach as using Stack/Dock panels in WPF.

[image]

Additionally, you can play with the `TableLayoutPanel` as well.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar problem and this work around has fixed it (with anchors, every time I opened my solution, it showed me I had unsaved chagnes and diffing used to show different sizes and locations). Now The priblem is gone, however I still have one unresolved mystery! When I close and open the solution, VS shows me that I have unsaved changes to my Form, but the files seem to be identical when diffing the one in VS (after saving the unknown changes) against one that I saved before closing the solution.

Comment: One possible reason: If you use custom controls with new properties you should check whether the `DefaultValue` attribute is set correctly for the new properties. But sometimes the original controls can cause such symptoms as well, especially for derived forms/user controls.

Comment: thanks for the comment, all I have is 3 buttons, a text box, progress bar and a label! But Im glad that the re-arrenging/re-locating/re-sizing problem is solved. because at one point all my buttons became so small that the text on them became unreadable during beta testing and that was when I discovered the issue!