# Windows Forms weird control size in different computer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a weird issue with my application.

**How it works normally**

The form I'm showing works fine on every pc I've installed the application except one (I'll describe the problem later).

This is the form at minimum possible size.

[image]

If I resize the for It works properly, as you can see in this other image.

[image]

It works well and it fits perfectly.

**What I've done**

All the controls of the form are anchored correctly and distributed in subcontrols, panels and everything needed to resize properly. 
AutoScaleMode in all views is set to font.

This works well on every Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10 I've tried (I'm on Windows 10 right now).

I've modified DPI on my own computer and it still resizes properly.

I've changed screen resolution and it resizes properly (although I'm currently working at 1920x1080).

I've changed system font size and it works well.

**So, where is the problem?**

Here it comes the weird issue. There is one computer (Windows 7, 1920x1080, 100% DPI) where the app does no resize properly. Central controls (datagridview and preview / compare boxes) appear with very small size. Then, if I resize the form those controls resize according to bottom and right anchors, as expected. Here is a pic that shows this.

[image]

Can anyone give me an explanation of why is this working that way just in one computer? (As i said, I've tried other W7 pcs and it works well).

Greetings.

Comment: This looks like software environment issue. Try reinstalling framework, do windows updates, etc. Which framework version are you targeting? Try installing on that PC exact framework your application need.

Comment: I'm developing it on .NET framework 4. Why other framework could cause that issue? I mean, In the installer I've defined as dependency .NET Framework 4 and I've never had any kind of problem due to that.

Comment: Is there some additional window manager software at this PC? I mean something like this: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/program-to-save-visible-windows-locations-and-later-restore-the-layout http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-window-manager-resizer-arranger.htm   These can be a source of problem.

Comment: Nope. There is no window manager software installed.

Comment: Are you doing the anchoring programatically on this panel or with the designer? As far as I can tell its only the 3 middle controls that don't get resized correctly which would indicate to me that it might not be a machine config problem.

Comment: Have you tried what happen if you start the form maximized? Check also the AutoSize property of the problematic controls

Comment: I'd also try to enclose the central controls in panels and see if that solves the issue

Comment: Could you use the VS debugger on that issue PC ?

Comment: Anchor properties are set in VS designer for all 3 central controls. Resizing is not the problem, since if I maximize the form those controls grow accordingly to the anchors. The problem is that the **initial size** is smaller than expected.

Comment: If the problem is the initial size, try to put those 3 controls in a panel. I barely remember a problem like yours solved that way

Comment: Assuming that is a possible solution, it would be wonderful to know why the hell this issue only happens in that PC.

Comment: I can not assure it is a solution, and can't explain what happens in that PC. I think my problem had to do with the form being bigger than screen and on form resizing sizes being not calculated right or something like that, but i really am not sure :)

Comment: Could you set a minimum Size of the controls that is greater and see if you still run into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Anchoring can cause sometimes surprises in WinForms. One possible solution is to use always the `Dock` property and dock/stack the elements, similarly to WPF. You can achieve everything with invisible panels and by setting the `Dock`, `Padding` and `Margin` properties.

See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142897/5114784

Comment: As I said, the problem is that those controls are loaded with less size than expected. Anchor and/or Dock properties work well and are well set in the form.

Comment: The grid seems to be anchored, since it stretches as you resize the form. Instead, you should dock it to avoid such problems.