# Dynamically resize WinForms controls when Form is resized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms project on which I would like all of the controls to grow proportionally along with the form as the form is resized. This is what the form looks like in normal state: [Normal State Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H0jT.png)

I have tried setting the `Anchor` properties to their appropriate values given the location of each control on the form, and while it does move the controls, they remain the same size. I tried using the `AutoSize` property, but also to no avail. Here is what the form looks like after being maximized with the `Anchor` properties set: [Maximized Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTA6X.png)

I also tried using a formula from [Shaun Halverson](https://github.com/ShaunHalverson/ResizeButton/commit/7323081c054c7f98e410479eb497cc5a7453194f) to dynamically resize everything but it does not relocate the control properly, and I can't seem to figure out why. Here is the code I used to try and resize dynamically:

```
        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            originalFormSize = new Rectangle(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
            submitBtnOriginal = new Rectangle(submitButton.Location.X, submitButton.Location.Y, submitButton.Width, submitButton.Height);
        }
        private void Main_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resizeControl(submitBtnOriginal, submitButton);
        }

        private void resizeControl(Rectangle r, Control c)
        {
            float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(originalFormSize.Width);
            float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(originalFormSize.Height);

            int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
            int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);

            int newX = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
            int newY = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);  

            c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
            c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
        }
```

When I run this code, it moves the button to the opposite corner of the form, but it resizes it properly.

This would obviously be quite redundant given that I have to get an original size for every control I want to resize, but I would be fine with that if I could get dynamic resizing to work. I am surprised that this is not a more common problem, and I couldn't find hardly anything on this specific topic other than to use the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties. Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing? Is this a more difficult problem than it seems?

Comment: No, use layout panels (`TableLayoutPanel`, `FlowLayoutPanel` ....) and make sure to make your app `Dpi-Aware`.

Comment: You need some [TableLayoutPanels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel) -- You shouldn't add your Controls directly to a Form, use other Containers instead, which can also be nested (e.g., run Inspect or Spy++ and see how the Visual Studio interface is organized).  -- Note that you have mainly Textboxes and Labels: the former only resize in width, the latter depends on the AutoSize property - Define a MinimumSize and a MaximumSize or your Form. - You may need a different layout anyway.

Comment: although the OP has already said it's winform, but it's goog to  know tough tasks like resizing are mucher easier in wpf.

Comment: @LeiYang: Changing to your preferred platform is maybe a too radical suggestion. And I wouldn't say it's easier; it's just simply cleaner because you cannot mix stocking/docking/arbitrary size/grid layout as these bahaviors belong to the containers in WPF. Yes, WinForms is old, anchoring can be [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32121496/5114784) but you can solve everything with a clean approach. And as others said, a `TableLayoutPanel` can be a good solution here.

Comment: Thanks to the tip from @Jimi, I was able to figure it out. Using multiple nested TableLayoutPanels along with a formula to calculate the appropriate proportional Font size for Labels and TextBoxes, while complex, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Put TextBox `anchor` property values as `Top, Bottom, Left, Right` and resize the form. That should work.