# User control won't resize properly when run outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, layout, highdpi

I'm developing a WinForms app using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6. My app makes extensive use of user controls, which are part of the same project. Very often, user controls are anchored so that they resize with their parent panel or form. My user controls resize fine when I run the app from within Visual Studio, either in debug mode (F5) or without debugging (Ctrl+F5). However, they fail to resize properly when I run the compiled EXE file from File Explorer.

I wrote a small demo app to reproduce the issue. This is my demo app running from within Visual Studio.

[image: App running from inside Visual Studio]

My user control has a black border. The "Some message" label is top-left aligned, and the OK button is anchored to the bottom right. This looks fine.

The following screenshot shows the same app when run from File Explorer.

[image: App running from File Explorer]

As you can see, the user control border is resizing fine, but the OK button fails to anchor to the bottom right as it shows when run from within Visual Studio.

I have searched online but I couldn't find any approaches to diagnose or fix this. Any ideas? Thank you.

**EDIT**. I suspect this may be related to Visual Studio running as a DPI-unaware process (no scaling). I use a high-DPI monitor so the WinForms designer needs that I use [Visual Studio with no scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2022). I tried to restart Visual Studio as a DPI-aware process, but it won't do it. Every time I restart it, I get the message that it is at 100% scaling. There is no `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\devenv.exe` key in the Registry. How can I revert it to the default DPI-aware setting?

**EDIT 2**. When I set the `ApplicationHighDpiMode` option in the project file to `DpiUnawareGdiScaled`, the app scales fine even when run as a stand-alone EXE, but is a bit blurry. When I set the option to `PerMonitorV2`, the app looks better on screen but fails to scale properly as described in my original question. Switching to .NET 7 has no effect to either option. Of course, I could set `ApplicationHighDpiMode` to `DpiUnawareGdiScaled` and forget about the problem, but (1) I want to know why this is failing and (2) I would like my app to be DPI-aware and run nicely on both standard DPI and high-DPI settings.

Comment: Add the Button to a Panel docked to Bottom -- BTW, note the different sharpness of the two images. What does this say? -- Since you probably can, move to .NET 7 now

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks, but I am not sure what the different sharpness is saying. BTW, moving to .NET 7 doesn't have any effects on this problem.

Comment: The different sharpness of the two images (strongly) suggests that the first one represents an App that is not DpiAware, the second, well, the opposite. Hence, your App, most probably, becomes DpiAware at run-time, after the LayoutEngine kicks in the first time. Could be caused by WPF libraries (or Control libraries that use PresentationFramework assemblies), or calls to the Shell (i.e., FileDialog *elements*) -- Moving to .NET 7+ should ensure that, at least, a `SystemAware` DpiAwareness (should be `PerMonitorV2`) is set before any Form is created. Unless you have disabled it on purpose

Comment: @Jimi: I have added some new details to my question. As you can see, I am running VS with no scaling (and I can't get it back to default mode), and the behaviour of the stand-alone app (EXE file) varies depending on the project options. Still, this doesn't solve the problem, as I want the app to be DPI aware. Is there a way to create a WinForms DPI-aware app that scales properly?

Comment: If you have actually made your App DpiAware, which in .NET 7 implies setting `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode‌​>` in the main `<PropertyGroup>` of your Project file (don't mess with `app.manifest`, that's just used to set the supported Systems, as in .NET Framework 4.7.1+), then - as mentioned - use nested container (docked / anchored) to host your child Controls. Don't slap them directly onto the main ContainerControl (your UC, here)

Comment: @Jimi: That works, many thanks. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Also, why is the extra panel necessary? Any clues?

Comment: In WinForms anchoring has always been problematic for derived/composited user controls and forms. I will not copy-paste my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142897/5114784) for a similar question (even though I could get a bounty) but there I explain how you can achieve everything by docking. In this case, an invisible `Panel` docked to the bottom, and a `Button` docked to the right within the panel can be a good solution.