# Drawing Rectangle around all objects in Windows form Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I use rectangles which are around my objects (like buttons, labels, etc) to automatically adjust their size and location with Maximized window.

Here is my functions and codes.

```
private async Task ResizeControlAsync(Control c, Rectangle r) // resize buttons, panels, etc.
        {
            float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Width);
            float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Height);
            int newX = (int)(r.X * xRatio);
            int newY = (int)(r.Y * yRatio);

            int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
            int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);
            
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    c.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {

                            if (!isminimized)
                            {
                                c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
                                c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
                               
                            }
                    }));
                });
        }
```

```
private async void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isminimized = WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized;
            

            //resize_page(Pages);
            await ResizeControlAsync(MainPanel_BehindPagesObject, rec_MainPanel_BehindPagesObject);
            await ResizeControlAsync(MainPanel_Background, rec_MainPanel_Background);
            await ResizeControlAsync(SeparatorLine, rec_SeparatorLine);

            // Menu Panel
            await ResizeControlAsync(MenuPanel, rec_MenuPanel);
            //await ResizeControlAsync(Pad_Small, rec_Pad_Small);
            

            await ResizeControlAsync(MainButton, rec_MainButton);
            await ResizeControlAsync(DisplayButton, rec_DisplayButton);
            ...


        }
```

rec_Object_Name, are rectangles that I have defined like this manually:

```
        private Rectangle rec_MainPanel_BehindPagesObject;
        private Rectangle rec_MainPanel_Background;
        private Rectangle rec_SeparatorLine;

        // first panel (connection) 
        private Rectangle rec_ConnectionPanel;
        private Rectangle rec_ConnectButton;     // rec is abbreviation of rectangle.
        private Rectangle rec_RefreshPorts;      // rec is abbreviation of rectangle.
```

I want to make this process easier. In fact defining rec around every single object is a burden!
Furthermore I am calling ResizeControlAsync for every Item in Form1_Resize!!!

This takes a lot of time and its not clean at all!!

I tried codes like this to find all objects in my app and create a rec around them. However, no object is found using this code. Consequently no new rectangles would be created!

To make it short:
`// Get all controls on the form

```
var controls = this.Controls;
```

`
controls return empty!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create a new instance of your form
        Form form = new Form();

        // Define a list to store the rectangles
        List<Rectangle> rectangles = GetRectanglesAroundControls(form);

        // Use the rectangles as needed

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<Rectangle> GetRectanglesAroundControls(Control parentControl)
    {
        List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

        AddControlRectangles(parentControl, rectangles);

        return rectangles;
    }

    static void AddControlRectangles(Control control, List<Rectangle> rectangles)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = GetRectangleAroundControl(control);
        rectangles.Add(rectangle);

        // Recursively process child controls
        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            AddControlRectangles(childControl, rectangles);
        }
    }

    static Rectangle GetRectangleAroundControl(Control control)
    {
        Point location = control.Location;
        Size size = control.Size;
        return new Rectangle(location, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Creating a `Rectangle` around each control doesn't really make sence, since each `Control` has it's own Rectangle already (either `Location` and `Size` or `ClientRectangle` if you are just interested in a Forms Content.)

Rather than manualy resizing and adjusting, you should definitly get familiar with the `Anchor`-Property of each control. Setup properly, every control just automatically resizes without the need to do any manual resize of any kind. `SplitPanels` provide a way to have a forms layout adapt to size changes efficently as well.

We have a huge Forms Application and beside some special cases like "centering" there is absolutely no need to manually adjust any control to achieve a fluid layout.

---

Based on your comments it seems, that you want to achieve something like "My Form growed by 50%, so every control should grow by 50%". That is a very unnatural and unintuitive behaviour for applications.

Usually you have one control (or list) that forms the central object, while others are arranged around it beeing support-elements.

With Anchoring it is now easy to say: Main Element anchors to all 4 Edges, hence is perfectly growing with the form, while all other elements anchor on maximum 2 Edges (top left, bottom right, etc) to maintain their relative position on the form, but KEEP their size.

For your use-case the best shot to achieve what you want would be a `tableLayoutPanel`:

- Define a certain number of columns / rows.
- Set each column / row to consume `1/count`% of `height` respectively `width`
- Think of this new boxes as your new `layoutPixels` any control could consume:

[image]

[image]

Now, you could add a `control`, provide a `row` and `column` span, set it's dock mode to `fill` - and have the control grow or shrink relatively with the forms size in all dimensions:

[image]

[image]

This way, you could leave up all the resizing to windows forms and just define that a control starts in Box 4/5 with a rowspan of 1 and a colspan of 2, so it'll be (in the 5/5 example) always bottom right with a relative width of 40% and a height of 20%.

You could theoretically build a Grid made out of 100 columns and 100 rows, allowing you to "set" controls heights, widths and locations in 1% steps.

(I'd have one empty form ready containing just the table, where you always could copy the 100/100 table to new forms you are creating)

Based on the overall complexity, 50/50 or 25/25 may be sufficent as well, making placement in the Designer a bit easier. For a Real 100/100 i'd add some Logic, to manually place controls in the right spot to account for any
imperfections in the narrow designer view. (Or just manually modify the designer generated code, after draging a control to a random spot)

Something among the lines:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PlaceControl(this.button1, 3, 2, 4, 1);
}

private void PlaceControl(Control control,  int col, int colSpan, int row, int rowSpan)
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(control);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(control, col, row);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(control, colSpan);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(control, rowSpan);
}
```

Comment: I am familiar with anchor. 
But how anchor is going to help with resizing?!

when user resizes the window manually anchor might help moving them, but it does not affect their size.

However, I like to know about the default rec around objects! it might help me decrease my code. how can I access that?

Comment: Also, I searched for the rectangles that you mentioned. It seems like you are wrong.
However, maybe I didn't understand you well. 


If you have any way to make this better, I'll be glad to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: @KianFarooghi see [How to dock and anchor controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-8.0). You anchor each button or other control to one or more edges of its parent, that way it follows that edge when the parent is resized. If it is anchored to both left and right edges it will change size.

Comment: Just be careful with anchoring, it can have [side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32121496/5114784).

Comment: @KianFarooghi as mentioned by JonasH, you can anchor to multiple edges, hence a control will grow with the form. However, it seems like you want to achieve something like: "My Form is made 25% bigger, so every control should be 25% bigger". That would be tricky and you mainly should think about, if that makes sence? Usually a view is made of an central element (holding the main data) and other elements arranged around it to provide functionality. Now, with Anchoring it is pretty easy to say: "Central Element should grow, while others should maintain relative positioning, but keep their size".

Comment: @KianFarooghi having 2 elements share the growth could be done with a Splitpanel and both controls docking into one (child)panel. But doing this (dynamically) for every control on the page will be a mess.

Comment: @KianFarooghi Please see my comment update for a solution that may be easier to achieve.

Comment: @dognose 
Your edited answer seems promising. 
Thanks.


Do you have any idea about setting font size of labels and buttons with window size??

Comment: @KianFarooghi Probably the easiest way would be to have one "parent" form (Say `ScalableForm : Form` and every other form is inheriting from that (`MyConcreteForm : ScalableForm`). Then, you could override the `OnResize` event for `ScaleableForm` and iterate throough `this.Controls` to adapt font-sizes where needed.

Answer (score 0):

After Trying tableLayoutPanel I noticed different troubles that It creates for me.

Consequently, I decided to optimize my previous solution.
In fact I changed my code and now I create rectangles around all objects easily. Then I use these rectangles to change location and size of my objects.

```
Dictionary<Control, Rectangle> GetControlMap(Control parent, Type controlType)
    {
        Dictionary<Control, Rectangle> map = new Dictionary<Control, Rectangle>();

        IEnumerable<Control> controls = GetAll(parent, controlType);

        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

            rect.Location = new Point(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y);
            rect.Size = new Size(control.Width, control.Height);

            map.Add(control, rect);
        }

        return  map;
    }
```

in form1:

```
    List<Dictionary<Control, Rectangle>> ItemsWithText = new List<Dictionary<Control, Rectangle>>();
    List<Dictionary<Control, Rectangle>> OtherItems = new List<Dictionary<Control, Rectangle>>();



 ItemsWithText.Add(GetControlMap(this, typeof(Label)));
 ItemsWithText.Add(GetControlMap(this, typeof(Button)));
 // add more items if you need to. Items Like Panel,etc.
```

fuction for changing location and size of the objects:
// This is a little bit messy. I try to edit this part Later.

```
private async Task ResizeControlAsync(Control c, Rectangle r) // resize buttons, panels, etc.
    {
        float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Width);
        float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(formOriginalSize.Height);
        int newX = (int)(r.X * xRatio);
        int newY = (int)(r.Y * yRatio);

        int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
        int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);
        
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                c.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!isminimized)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
                                c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                                MessageBox.Show("Error In Resize - Check Resolution of the screen");
                            }

                            if ( (c.GetType() == typeof(Label) ||
                                  c.GetType() == typeof(BunifuButton2) ||
                                  c.GetType() == typeof(Button) ||
                                  c.GetType() == typeof(BunifuThinButton2) ) &&
                                 ( isFirstTime || isMaximized || (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)) )

                            {
                                await ChangeFontSize(c, isMaximized, screenWidth, screenHeight);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // In case of minimizing the page, it returns an error. The error is circumvented by The Try-Catch.
                        // However !isminimized controls this error as well.
                    }
                }));
            });
    }
```

Form1_Resize event handler:

```
private async void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isminimized = WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized;

        foreach (Dictionary<Control, Rectangle> map in ItemsWithText)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in map)
            {
                Control control = kvp.Key;
                Rectangle rect = kvp.Value;

                await ResizeControlAsync(control, rect);
            }
        }

        foreach (Dictionary<Control, Rectangle> map in OtherItems)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in map)
            {
                Control control = kvp.Key;
                Rectangle rect = kvp.Value;

                await ResizeControlAsync(control, rect);
            }
        }
```

**This might seem so long, But it is much easier than using tableLayoutPanel while creating your project.**

You can Copy and Paste the functions:)